Odorless color less , transparent fluid is leaking underneath my car
i am getting an issue in my Hyundai i10 2009 Car, the car is park for more than 12 hours now ,
i didn't use the AC for more than 2 days now, so i don't think coming from condensation , i drove it yesterday without ac , its been 12 hours now since have parked it Now Odorless color less , transparent fluid is leaking underneath my car , it is neither sticky or greasy nor fuel , precisely below the driving seat
video is attached , its seems to be a kind of tank where its coming from



Has it been raining, or have you been though a car wash?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

yes its rain water

I was going to a say it was Iocane water, but you would need to know the princess Bride to get the reference.

Got it  because of some issues with the boot fittings some rain water accumulated in boot itself ,its kind of drain tank what i have showed in picture , and the black point showing in picture is the rubber cork holding it all ,i just pulled it out and the remaining water got drained , now its looking good

I would start the car and run the AC with it idling in place. Is the drip in the same place? It is possible that the AC drain is glogged so water builds up and slowly leaks out. Running the Defroster will also generate moisture as the AC runs (regardless of the temp setting) to help remove humidity from the cabin air.

Two things ... this is the rear end of the vehicle ... the AC wouldn't drain here. Secondly, the OP stated they haven't been running the AC. Not sure how doing what you're suggesting would have anything to do with what is going on with the vehicle.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - I'm basing it off of the images provided. The part just to the right of the circle in the images (silver-ish, sticking down) is the mounting point for the rear suspension. If you divide the car in 1/2, this is the rear of the vehicle. The rear of the driver's seat would not be where an AC would be draining. Besides, this is the passenger side of the vehicle. Also, this is rain water, as stated by the OP.

If you have a sunroof, there are four points in each corner that allow rain water to drain underneath the car.
